# NserviceBus: How to set timeout for the request/reply message

Tags: nservicebus

I use nservicebus with rabbitmq and I send a message like this:

```
BusControl.Request<MessageResponse>(message, Cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

But I never receive a response if some errors occur in the consumer or if the endpoint is offline.
How to set timeout for the request/reply message? I want to receive a response after 30 seconds even with a timeout error.

Comment: Is that NServiceBus API code or do you have some king of your own code on top of NServiceBus?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NServiceBus 6 callback client never gets a callback when the request handler fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48675609/nservicebus-6-callback-client-never-gets-a-callback-when-the-request-handler-fai)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in our documentation: https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/callbacks#cancellation